# Accessing password protected MS Access file

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have encrypted an Access file via the encryption option under File > Info.

In Excel when I try to retrieve a table from the Access file it pops up a password box but it doesn't accept my password. I can link from Access file to Access file no problems.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Solved. I went to File Access options Client settings and set the encrption method to "Use Legacy Encryption" then redid the password.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, if the settings will let you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved. I went to File Access options Client settings and set the encrption method to "Use Legacy Encryption" then redid the password