# Connecting to an encrypted Access database after changing the Encryption Method

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Based on  [Accessing Password Protected MS Access file from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523716/accessing-password-protected-ms-access-file-from-excel), I should be able to go to Options > Client Settings and set the Encryption Method to "Use Legacy Encryption" and then be able to connect to my encrypted database through Excel Data Connections. However, when I do this, I still get prompted for the password repeatedly and eventually have to hit Cancel (and thus get no connection).

I am using Excel 2010 and Access 2010. My database is encrypted and has linked tables (as well as many queries, forms, reports, macros and VBA code).

Can anyone help me solve why this isn't working?

Comment: You did re-encrypt the file after changing the Encryption Method setting, did you?

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson! That did it. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the "Encryption Method" setting for a database in the Microsoft Access settings does not automatically re-encrypt the file with the new encryption method. You must un-encrypt and re-encrypt the file for the new encryption method to take effect.